# Is it possible to connect to a 2nd external WordPress Database within WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, wordpress

I am trying to find a way to hook several satellite WordPress installations into a centralized installation of WordPress in order to pull post data and custom field meta from two custom post types from the central installation and display this data on the satellite sites.

Is there any way to create a database connection to another WordPress database either on the same server, or on a DIFFERENT server, and then use STANDARD WORDPRESS LOOP METHODOLOGY to retrieve and display data from that second WordPress database, whilst still maintaining the ability to retrieve posts/pages from the original native database?

Sorry if this is a complicated question. I have been Googling for several hours and have even tried to write a couple of solutions myself which failed spectacularly.

Would most definitely appreciate any help and advise and if anyone could post some code ideas, that would be great!

Comment: Does it have to be a back end connection? You could use the rest api plugin and just make the requests in your preferred method (front end json or back end curl, etc): http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

Comment: There doesn't need to be anything pulled into the back end. The data from the external database only needs to be shown front end.  We do need to be able to pull the custom post meta from the external custom posts.

Comment: The mentioned plugin could work for you then. Custom post info may not be a part of the API but you could probably modify it easily. Like any sane API plugin available, it is likely limited to core functionality and may not be 100% complete. Worth looking into though

Comment: This looks like an option but I would honestly prefer a more typical PHP / SQL solution. Connecting to the central database in such a way that I can use something close to the standard WordPress Query to create a loop.